# ERROR 1064 (42000) when importing .text file

Tags: mysql

tried to upload a .text file to MySQL Workbench to create a table and I get an error: `ERROR 1064 (42000) near ' ■/ ' at line 1`

The .text file is pipe delimited

```
BuildingID|Class       |ListingStatus|
B-12345   |BuildingSale|Active       |
```

Comment: And your .text file, how does it look like?

Comment: Depending on how you created the text file, there may be invisible characters at the beginning of the file that the Workbench does not like. As invisible characters won't show up in a post in here, please try to create a Hex dump of your file's content using a converter tool like [this one](http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-hex-convertor.php) and post the first 6 digits from the result. And more importantly, how did you create the text file?

Comment: Importing expects the file to be SQL commands, not a pipe-delimited text file.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you. It does seems like that's the reason.